# How to get the http satus value?

Tags: angular, http, status

I'm trying to get the value of the http status
Some kind of :

```
    export class StepsComponent implements OnInit {
        status: number;
    }
```

And later in a function :

```
    timer(){
        this.status = http.response.status;
    }
```

I do not want to catch the error, because I want to display something when the status is 200, so when it's OK..

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Please provide some code describing how you perform the http request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do something similar if you are using angularV2.

```
http.get(
    url,
    {observe: 'response'}
)
  .subscribe(response => {    
    // Access status:
    console.log(response.status);    
    // Access header:
    console.log(response.headers.get('Header-Name-To-Look-At'));
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I put the value in a var ?

Comment: this.status = response.status?

Comment: You should really learn variables, scoping and callbacks before diving deep.